# Implementing custom 404 error page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I've customized the design for the 404 page - however, I'm having trouble implenting it.

I've learned quickly that for one you have to embed the CSS directly into the HTML - and secondly it doesn't seem like I can use html.erb or embedded ruby in other words. With that said, what is the best way for me to implement the following design code to my 404.html page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>New Error Design</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="css/mediaquery.css" rel="stylesheet">

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/selectify.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 logo">
          <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>



        <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
            <a href="sign-in.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info sign-i-u">Sign IN</button></a>
            <a href="sign-up.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info sign-i-u">Sign Up</button></a>
        </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 error_text">
            <h1> Sorry, the page you requested is not found</h1>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
                <%= link_to 'sign Up', new_user_registration_path, class: "btn btn-primary buttons_style" %>
                <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path, class: "btn btn-primary buttons_style" %>
                <%= link_to 'Return To Home', root_path, class: "btn btn-primary buttons_style" %>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <footer>
        <div class="container">
        <p class="f-logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/footer_logo.png" alt="logo-image"></a></p>
        <p class="links">
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Privacy</a>
        <a href="#">Terms</a>
        <a href="#">Copyright</a>
        </p>
        <p class="copy">2014 © Company name. All Rights Reserved</p>
      </div>
    </footer>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this will mostly be opinion based, here's how I've done it...

I prefer to have a Rails template which I can use to generate the HTML for a 404 page, then simply save that page in the `public/` folder of the app.  This way, when the app changes, I can quickly visit a route to generate the 404 page, then save the HTML to the `public/` directory.

Make sure you set up your application to use the custom pages.  [Rambling Labs has a good example](http://ramblinglabs.com/blog/2012/01/rails-3-1-adding-custom-404-and-500-error-pages) of how to do this.